# Simple formula comprehension: help medical worker who are struggling to understand AI

Tags: artificial-intelligence, bayesian-network

https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-020-17419-7

I am a medical school graduate and I really want to learn AI/ML for computer-aided diagnosis.

I was building a symptom checker and I found the material. It clarifies the drawbacks of associative models which are performing differential diagnosis. And it suggests counterfactual(causal) approach to improve accuracy.

The thing is I couldn't understand what the formulas mean in the article, e.g.:

[image: P(D∣E;θ)]

I really want to know what | and ; are doing here, what do they mean, etc.

I would really happy if someone can directly answer or just provide me some references to get general idea quickly.

Comment: The paper defines it quite clearly: $P(D|\mathcal{E}; \theta)$ is the likelihood of a fault component $D$ given findings $\mathcal{E}$ using a model $\theta$. It's just mathematical syntax for writing that English statement more concisely. What's your background in probability theory? Maybe you can pick up an introductory book or resource, or take some university course(s) on that or other relevant topics.

Comment: See [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) on Wikipedia too.